# Did i commit shirk?

Tags: shirk, tawba, forgiveness, internet

I was on Youtube recently and a video came on my homepage. the title was "what does your husband look like later" i clicked on it and i had to choose a card. And then she started to tell things. but I didn't notice until later I thought I may have committed shirk. plss reply if i committed shirk because i'm really scared and i've already asked for forgiveness but i'm afraid i'm punished.

Comment: Shirk requires disbelief or belief that there's another diety. I can't find any of this in your post.

Answer (score -1):

This is a kind of sorcery! The Prophet Sallallaahualaihiwasallam صلى الله عليه وسلم mentioned about Kuffur and Shirk who even just sit or listen to any kind of sorcery knowingly!

But you didn’t know, so that ruling doesn’t apply to you!

You are ok inshaAllah!

Just be carful next time!

Comment: thank you very much for responding. I was crying for days because I thought I did something bad. Thank you I am now reassured