# i dont know if i commit shirk or not?

Tags: shirk, forgiveness

I was on Youtube recently and a video came on my homepage. the title was "what does your husband look like later" i clicked on it and i had to choose a card. And then she started to tell things. but I didn't notice until later I thought I may have committed shirk. plss reply if i committed shirk because i'm really scared and i've already asked for forgiveness but i'm afraid i'm punished. But i dont believ in anything else exept Allah. Did i still commit shirk?

Comment: Please stop repeating the same question again and again of you want to edit a question register on the site.

Comment: @Medi1Saif  answer my question than

Comment: I've already explained that your question is nonsense there's no relation between what you describe and shirk.

Comment: @Medi1Saif  i asked this question because i read that if you go to someone that tells the future you commit shirk, and my question is did i commit shirk or not

Comment: @Medi1Saif plss reply.

Comment: @Medi1Saif can you reply on me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did i commit shirk?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/58350/did-i-commit-shirk)